How to change author list in Authors dropdown in edit page display all user role if user logged as admin type of role
Author dropdown
I am using classic editor and in edit page herer is a 'Author' dropdown and I want to modify value of this edit page (post type = 'page') authors dropdown. I want to show all users in this author dropdown of in edit page only when user logged as Admin/Administrator role type.
Want to change the list of users in the Author select dropdown on the edit page for Admin/Administrator role type users. I tried but not working for post type page.
I have 3 admin role user and when i logged as one of admin role type user i want all users are show in this author dropdown so admin can set any type of user as page(post type = page) author. currently by default only editors names are displaying in this author dropdown and i want to show all users.
I tried this without check user role but is not working for me in edit page in worpdress.
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', 'change_user_dropdown', 10, 2 );

function change_user_dropdown( $query_args, $r ){
    // get screen object
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // list users whose role is e.g. 'Author' for 'post' post type
    if( $screen->post_type == 'page' ):
        $query_args['role'] = array('Author');

        // unset default role 
        unset( $query_args['who'] );
    endif;

    

    return $query_args;
}


what do you need in this dropdown is the user is not administrator ?

I have 3 admin role user and when i logged as one of admin role type user i want all users are show in this author dropdown so admin can set any type of user as page(post type page) author. currently by default admin can see editors name in this author dropdown.

add_filter('wp_dropdown_users_args', function ($query_args, $r) {
if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    unset($query_args['who']);
}
return $query_args;
}, 10, 2);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Thank you for solution but this answer is not working.

@jeremy I edit this now

@Sunshine just modify current_user_can('administrator') as per your needs. it should be work.

@Nilesh: Your edit provides no explanation.

@Nilesh Given solution is not working for me in edit page is display same as default dropdown.

as you don't explain if there is something to change when non administrator users edit a page, here is my answer to change the author list when the connected user has the capability edit_others_pages. you can change it according to your needs.
note also that the filter wp_dropdown_users_args works only on classical editor (like we see it on your screenshot) and not on gutenberg editor.
add_filter("wp_dropdown_users_args", function ($query_args, $parsed_args) {
    
    // the capability "edit_others_pages" can be change to another linked at the reason of the customisation
    if (current_user_can("edit_others_pages")) {
        
        // remove the filter on capabilities to return all users
        unset($query_args["capability"]);
        
    }
    
    
    return $query_args;
    
}, 10, 2);

